# How can I stop a user registration thank you page being cached in Craft 2

Tags: cache, craft2

I seem to have an issue with a thank you page on user registration in craft 2. The thank you page gets passed a modified  users id which is shown to the the registrant.

However some odd occasions have occurred where a user gets the user id of an already registered user from a few weeks previously. The only way this can happen it seems to me is if the user gets someone else's thank you page from the cache - the signup handling behind the process is solid.

When I look in template cache table has a lot of entries (stalled task not clearing?) I can see the thank you page has lots of caches eg "site:sign-up-thank-you" with the same key. There are no cache tags in the page.

Could this be the cause of the mystery and how can i stop the thank you page being cached or give it a unique key?

Comment: If it's caching, you might have cache tags in a parent maybe?

Comment: I think i solved by excluding the site from server level nginx micro caching and clearing the queue and fixing the stuck tasks. Monitoring and so far its fine